# Exclude multiple post types from Yoast sitemap

Tags: php, wordpress

There is a solution offered by Yoast to exclude 1 post type from the xml sitemap that it generates, but it does not explicitly state how to exclude multiple post types..
Here is the way they suggest you exclude 1 post type:

```
/**
 * Exclude a post type from XML sitemaps.
 *
 * @param boolean $excluded  Whether the post type is excluded by default.
 * @param string  $post_type The post type to exclude.
 *
 * @return bool Whether or not a given post type should be excluded.
 */
function sitemap_exclude_post_type( $excluded, $post_type ) {
    return $post_type === 'recipes';
}

add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_exclude_post_type', 'sitemap_exclude_post_type', 10, 2 );
```

See the [original documentation here](https://developer.yoast.com/features/xml-sitemaps/api/)

Answer (score -4):

The solution is to alter the code above as such, listing the post type you'd like to exclude in the array declaration:

```
function my_sitemap_exclude_post_type( $excluded, $post_type ) {
    $excludedPostTypes = array('portfolio', 'testimonial', 'area-item', 'cool_timeline', 'author');
    if (in_array($post_type, $excludedPostTypes)) 
        return true;
    return false;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_exclude_post_type', 'my_sitemap_exclude_post_type', 10, 2 );
```

In this case, the excluded items are:
'portfolio', 'testimonial', 'area-item', 'cool_timeline', 'author'

This solution was [provided by Yoast support here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/exclude-multiple-post-types-from-sitemap/)

Comment: The code contains syntax errors. I'm missing a closing curly brace. And why are there 2 return statements?

Comment: Friendly reminder that self-answering [is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). having a question, finding an answer, and posting here isn't a flag reason. If there's something else wrong with the question, [use standard flags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Comment: it's short for if(){}else{}

Comment: There's no syntax error!

Comment: i really don't get why there are so many downvotes, i know 2 of those on both the question and the answer are from people who don't like that i answered my own question.. The rest must be from people who read @jrswgtr mistaken comment..